# Как обрабатывать promise сразу после вызова запроса Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise, vuex

Проблема в том, что не понимаю как можно сразу получить ответ и обработать его, допустим есть mounted и computed методы, которые помогают спокойно получать данные:

```
mounted(){
    this.$store.dispatch('NAME_OF_ACTION')
},
computed: {
    getSth() { return this.$store.getters.NAME }
}
```

Но, что если нужно сразу получить какой то Promise и вставить данные из него?

```
this.$store.dispatch('NAME_OF_ACTION').then(promise => console.log(promise))
```

Таким образом ничего не получается получить, разве что какие то действия независящие от данного запроса

Соответственно как можно сразу обработать данные, какие есть варианты? (новичок во VUE)

Comment: Суть не ясна - нужна более внятная формулировка вопроса. Особенно в моментах "сразу получить какой то Promise", и "сразу обработать данные". По-умолчанию, **действия не резолвят результат, так как они в принципе не должны возвращать данные** вызывающему коду (это было бы неправильно, хоть и возможно технически). Для получения данных есть геттеры, и объект состояния.

Comment: Например при отправке формы получить статус запроса, исходя из него вывести сообщение: 200 = Спасибо, иначе = Ошибка

Comment: Из этого примера все так же непонятно, почему статус должен быть именно возвращаемым значением действия, а не свойством объекта состояния. Vuex нужен именно для управления состоянием. То что ты хочешь (возврат значения не через стейт), противоречит его схеме работы, основным его принципам... это *можно* реализовать, но сначала надо понять, для чего именно такая реализация. Если не для чего, без цели, то ответ будет вредным советом.